# Concatenating columns with aliases

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I've written a query that is working fine:

```
SELECT t1.first_names, t1.last_names, t2.role, t3.description, t2.start_date
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.worker_id=t1.ID
LEFT JOIN tabke3 t3
ON t3.role = t2.role
WHERE t2.role IN (
'BFLT',
'BFDTMC',
'BFTMC',
'BFPSOC',
'BFFOSW',
'BFCP',
'BFCW',
'BFDTM',
'BFT',
'BFFSW',
'BFPSO',
'BFSW',
'BFTM',
'BFYJS',
'BFYM',
'BFYW'
)
AND t2.end_date IS NULL
```

However I want to concatenate the first two columns (`first_names` and `last_names`) into one. I've tried to amend the first line but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT t1.first_names || ',' || t1.last_names, t2.role, t3.description, t2.start_date
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work means what?Do you get any errors?

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to work" mean - are you getting an error or not the result you want? Maybe give a sample and show what you get now and what you want to get. You might need to show the table definition too; perhaps the names are `char` instead of `varchar2` so you get unwanted padding? And what does this have to do with aliases?

Comment: The only thing I see if that you haven;t given the computed column an alias.  Something like `SELECT t1.first_names || ',' || t1.last_names AS Full_Name, t2.role, ...`

Comment: this code works fine, no problems with aliases `select name||','||surname,name, surname from (   select 'name' as name, 'surname' as surname from dual   )`

Comment: Your code is correct for Oracle.  Perhaps you are using a different database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.first_names || ',' || t1.last_names, t2.role, t3.description, t2.start_date
```

looks like it should run, would produce for example 'John,Doe'. I think that it's more usual to separate the first name form last name using space. Also, you should add a column alias so this code can be made into a view or referred to by other code.

```
SELECT t1.first_names || ' ' || t1.last_names as longname , t2.role, t3.description, t2.start_date
```

if you are getting an error, check your  quotes, oracle's sqlplus and sql developer don't like the "smart quotes" you get when using some office applications. You can tell you have smart quotes because ‘quote’ looks different from 'quote'

lastly, a guess: your columns are actually last_name and first_name:

```
SELECT t1.first_name || ' ' || t1.last_name as longname , t2.role, t3.description, t2.start_date
```